# What is happening with this array argument and its interaction with the stix package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, arrays, alignment, stix2

Ok so I am working on a tikz diagram and I decided to use a website called [mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/) and it exported some code which I modified in order for it to compile and include below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[geometry]{ifsym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
        
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
   %uncomment if require: \path (0,400); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 400

%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp5758355635496207] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}] (120.57,190) -- (220,190) -- (220,340) -- (120.57,340) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da45032070076001796] 
\draw    (120,320) -- (138,302) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5117572195696634] 
\draw    (188,254) -- (153,287) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7569286612079461] 
\draw    (202,238) -- (220,220) ;

% Text Node
\draw (156.43,250.43) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle \alpha $};
% Text Node
\draw (162,258.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\smblkcircle $};
% Text Node
\draw  [draw opacity=0]  (136,277) -- (160,277) -- (160,311) -- (136,311) -- cycle  ;
\draw (148,294) node   [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{13.6pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
$\displaystyle f$
\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (191.14,233.23) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{c}{{{\displaystyle}}}
g\\
\end{array}$};
% Text Node
\draw (131,202.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$a$};
% Text Node
\draw (198,312) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle b$};


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, in the original exported code, the 3rd from the bottom `\draw` command instead read

```
\draw (191.14,233.23) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
g\\
```

which gave an `Illegal character in the array argument` error, which prompted me to try to figure out how I could get it into a semiworkable state.

So, to my questions: first, what is the cause of this error? I downloaded the `stix2` package so that I could make use of the `\smlblkcircle` command, and I think there was some complaint in the compiler about the modification I did, despite this code actually outputting an image that is quite close to the one I wanted.
My second question is: how do I fix the code, either inline with the mathcha code, or my addition of the column argument, in order to align everything in my diagram much more nicely?

Comment: please provide a real test file that shows your issue. The code posted generates `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package textcomp` then has multiple errors as there is no `\begin{document}` you should remove any packages unrelated to the error that yo ar asking about. I get no array argument error.

Comment: `\begin{array}{{>` will generate an error as there is a spurious doubled `{`

Comment: Also, `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.\begin{tikzpicture}` does not make sense. As already mentioned, please post some compilable minimal code.

Comment: Both unfortunate errors on my part. Thanks for catching them. However, the part about doubling the `{` was that way in the original code. I agree it doesn't make much sense. Furthermore, removing it and its matching brace do not stop the error on that line from happenig. Putting in the `{c}` argument after `array` seemed to do the trick, although vscode still complained, I was able to reload the pdf and notice there was a diagram similar to the one I was looking for.

Comment: we really should not have to catch such errors, it is not too much to ask that you test before posting that the code that you post generates the error that you are asking about.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from. Still, I did get the code to stop outputting that error; the errors on here were from copy and pasting wrong. I wanted to, first, understand the error, which you have explained; thank you- I did not know I needed the `array` package. Furthermore I wanted to see how one would go about shifting some of the characters down so that the positioning looked better.

Comment: But I never got your code to show any characters at all, it had too many syntax errors to make output.

Comment: Understandable. I kept changing it- there were a few more. Hopefully now it compiles. Furthermore I got the characters to shift by changing the coordinates after draw slightly- fairly straightforward now that I think about it! I wonder if there was a more elegant solution though. Also I got some odd error related to a clash between `stix2` and `textcomp` related to `\UndeclareTextCommand{\textpertenthousand}{T1}`. Does that ring any bells?

Comment: don't use textcomp

Comment: Surely enough no conflict! And I can't remember why I had it at all- my document seems basically the same with or without it. Thank you for your patience and your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted example code produces multiple errors as it is missing `\begin{document}` and other issues.  The error in the title is unrelated to any of the code in that example, but in the final fragment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}} x \end{array}$
\end{document}
```

produces the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.
```

as the `array` package has not been loaded and so `>` is not a defined column type.

If you load `array` then it (accidentally) works

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}} x \end{array}$
\end{document}
```

However the extra `{}` group is just spurious and gets removed accidentally by TeX's low level argument parsing, if you added an extra column you would get the expected error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}l} x \end{array}$
\end{document}
```

produces

```
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (>{\displaystyle }l): `c' used.
```

Deleting the brace group fixes that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}ll} x \end{array}$
\end{document}
```